# Single FlaskForm rendered multiple times on one page using FOR loop

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm making an application where I need to render identical forms multiple times on one page (number of forms might be from 1 to 20). In the video below I'm using simple for loop over a range from 0 to 5, just for a test. When I input data into the first form and submit it, all data duplicates to other forms but I need the user to submit data of each form independently from others. In other words, the user can fill in data in some forms (in 1, in 2 or in all forms) and submit those data separately.

[Youtube video showing my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6aCoc9EH7M)

I have tried to change submit buttons manually with unique ids and names for each form but this didn't help.
I also tried to use Field Enclosures from WTForms but this also didn't help.

**Here is my FlaskForm** *I haven't included all fields to save space*

```
class EnvelopeForm(FlaskForm):
    vme_name = StringField('VME')
    outside_diameter = DecimalField('OD', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('build envelope')
```

**Here is my view handler**

```
@app.route('/bokeh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def nonuniform_ellipse():
form = EnvelopeForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    envelope = Envelopes(vme_name=form.vme_name.data,
                        outside_diameter=form.outside_diameter.data)
    db.session.add(envelope)
    db.session.commit()    
return render_template('vme.html', form=form)
```

**Here is HTML** *I haven't included all fields to save space.*

```
{% for i in range(0, 5) %}

 <form method="POST" action="" name="{{ i }}">
   {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div>
       {{ form.vne_name.label }}
       {{ form.vme_name }}
     </div>
     <div>
       {{ form.outside_diameter.label }}
       {{ form.outside_diameter }}
     </div>
     <div>
       {{ form.submit) }}
     </div>
   </form>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that they all share the same name, you should search for a way to pass different names into each "sub-form" to differentiate them. Just my first Idea. Dont know if this will work

Comment: I did pass different names like this `<form name="{{ i }}">` . It didn't work

Comment: here might be a solution for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897289/flask-wtf-same-form-on-same-page-using-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution as per @ser-zhm comment. Now I can render whatever forms I have in DB separately on each other as [it is shown on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFfoG.png).

But when I submit data from one of the forms it is always updates the last record in DB and not the particular row. Lets say I have three empty forms rendered on the page and three records (rows) in my DB with NULL data in each column name referring to each form fields [like it is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di6TE.png). When I fill in form #2, all the data is saved in row #3 instead of the row #2. So whatever form I fill in it is always the last record is updated.

How can I updated the particular row which is referring to the form ID?

**View handler**

```
@app.route('/envelope_forms_test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def nonuniform_ellipse():
    form_ids = list(map(str, [id[0] for id in 
                     Envelopes.query.with_entities(Envelopes.id).all()]))
    forms = []
    for form_id in form_ids:
        form = EnvelopeForm(prefix=form_id)
        forms.append(form)
    for form in forms:
        if form.submit.data and form.validate_on_submit():
            Envelopes.query.filter_by(id=form_id).\
                update({'vme_name': form.vme_name.data,
                        'outside_diameter': form.outside_diameter.data})          
            db.session.commit()
```

**Here is HTML**

```
{% for form in forms %}

<form method="POST" action="">
{{ form.csrf_token() }}
 <div>
   {{ form.vne_name.label }}
   {{ form.vme_name }}
  </div>
  <div>
   {{ form.outside_diameter.label }}
   {{ form.outside_diameter }}
  </div>
  <div>
   {{ form.submit) }}
  </div>
 </form>

{% endfor %}
```